# IF-Else Conditions in JoltTransformation in Apache Nifi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I am trying to implement if-else condition using jolt transformation to get the expected output, can anyone pls help me out:

Note:

1. if **`billentity`** is equal to **`AWS Marketplace`**

   then **`PriceToCustomer`** will be equal to **0**
2. else if **`billentity`** is equal to **`AWS`**

   then
   if **`LineItemType`** is equal to **`RecurringFee`**

   then **`unblendedCost`** value will be equal to **`PriceToCustomer`**

   elseif **`LineItemType`** is equal to **`tax`**

   then **`(unblendedCost value * tax value/100) + 1`** is equal to **`PriceToCustomer`**

   else **`LineItemType`** is equal to **`Usage`**

   then **`(unblendedCost value * Usage value/100) + 1`** will be equal to **`PriceToCustomer`**

**Input**:

```json
[
  {
    "billentity": "AWS Marketplace",
    "lineItemType": "tax",
    "unblendedCost": 10,
    "tax": 5.02
  },
  {
    "billentity": "AWS",
    "lineItemType": "tax",
    "unblendedCost": 10,
    "tax": 8.02
  },
  {
    "billentity": "AWS",
    "lineItemType": "Usage",
    "unblendedCost": 10,
    "Usage": 9.02
  }
]
```

**Expected Output**:

```json
[
  {
    "billentity": "AWS Marketplace",
    "lineItemType": "tax",
    "unblendedCost": 10,
    "tax": 5.02,
    "PriceToCustomer": 0
  },
  {
    "billentity": "AWS",
    "lineItemType": "tax",
    "unblendedCost": 10,
    "tax": 8.02,
    "PriceToCustomer": 1.802
  },
  {
    "billentity": "AWS",
    "lineItemType": "Usage",
    "unblendedCost": 10,
    "Usage": 9.02,
    "PriceToCustomer": 1.902
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional logic within a **shift** tranformation and computations within a **modify** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "tmp_bl": "=concat(@(1,billentity),'_',@(1,lineItemType))",
        "tmp_dv_100_tax": "=divideAndRound(2,100,@(1,tax))",
        "tmp_dv_uc_100_tax": "=divideAndRound(3,@(1,unblendedCost),@(1,tmp_dv_100_tax))",
        "tmp_utt": "=doubleSum(@(1,tmp_dv_uc_100_tax),1)",
        "tmp_dv_100_usg": "=divideAndRound(2,100,@(1,Usage))",
        "tmp_dv_uc_100_usg": "=divideAndRound(3,@(1,unblendedCost),@(1,tmp_dv_100_usg))",
        "tmp_utu": "=doubleSum(@(1,tmp_dv_uc_100_usg),1)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "tmp_bl": {
          "AWS Marketplace*": {
            "#0": "[&3].PriceToCustomer"
          },
          "AWS_tax": {
            "@2,tmp_utt": "[&3].PriceToCustomer"
          },
          "AWS_Usage": {
            "@2,tmp_utu": "[&3].PriceToCustomer"
          },
          "AWS_RecurringFee": {
            "@2,unblendedCost": "[&3].PriceToCustomer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // get rid of auxiliary attributes
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "tmp_*": ""
      }
    }
  },
  { // convert non-numeric "PriceToCustomer" values to numeric ones
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "PriceToCustomer": "=toDouble"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]

Comment: Yes, you're right, I've just fixed it @pandu